# Logging libraries for Erlang/OTP

Tags: logging, erlang, error-logging

For logging activity of an Erlang/OTP application, do you simply use a wrapper over [`disk_log`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/disk_log.html) or some other libraries?

Comment: A good note on performance when using `disk_log` can be found here (summary: `disk_log` is really fast!): http://timanovsky.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/correct-implementation-of-fast-server-logging-in-erlang/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also found:

- http://github.com/sinnus/ejabberd_logger
- http://github.com/etnt/elogger
- http://github.com/JacobVorreuter/log_roller

Answer (score 11):

There is standard error logging application SASL http://www.erlang.org/doc/system_principles/error_logging.html.

It can be configured to save logs on disk.

error_logger:info_report example usage:

```
2> error_logger:info_report([{tag1,data1},a_term,{tag2,data}]).
=INFO REPORT==== 11-Aug-2005::13:55:09 ===
    tag1: data1
    a_term
    tag2: data
ok
3> error_logger:info_report("Something strange happened").
=INFO REPORT==== 11-Aug-2005::13:55:36 ===
Something strange happened
ok
```

Also there is log4erl when you need different log format. You can look for real usage of it in [erlyvideo](http://github.com/erlyvideo/erlyvideo) project.

Comment: I thought it was only intended for logging errors: processes dying, etc. Not for the human-readable logs.

Comment: There is error_logger:info_report function that is useful for outputting your custom data.

Answer (score 10):

There is another option named [lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) from basho.

Answer (score 4):

Two libraries I've found: http://code.google.com/p/erlslug/ and http://github.com/ahmednawras/log4erl

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/siberian-fast-food/alogger