# How do I get rid of the erlang prompt on every line of my logs?

Tags: logging, console, erlang, prompt

When my game is running, I get all my normal io:format output, but infuriatingly, every output is preceded by the prompt:

```
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 1
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 2
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 3
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 4
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 5
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 6
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 7
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 8
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 9
(server@gamehost.thisplace.net)1> log entry 10
```

The desired result is:

```
log entry 1
log entry 2
log entry 3
....
```

I'm still on R14A, but will move up before too long.  If there's no quick and easy way to do it in my current version, what's the fast way to remove this annoyance in R15 and company?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to remove? node name and line number? i see line number is the same in every line..is this the full result in shell?

Answer (score 2):

try passing -noshell to erl when starting it. This will of course mean that you will have no shell.

Answer (score 1):

in erlang shell you can't remove line numbers. Maybe you may want to use file log with:

- error_logger: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/error_logger.html
- your own event_manager: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_event.html
- disk_log: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/disk_log.html
- ejabberd_logger: http://github.com/sinnus/ejabberd_logger

note that error_logger should do what you asked also in shell since the output will be similar to:

```
2> error_logger:warning_msg("Warnings tagged as: ~p~n", [warning]).
=ERROR REPORT==== 11-Aug-2005::13:45:49 ===
Serious error in my module
ok
```

more here: [Logging libraries for Erlang/OTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718101/logging-libraries-for-erlang-otp)